# assigning IP address to PC

Tags: ethernet, connection

i am configuring my PC to wipro mission 10X FPGA Board. But while configuring it is showing like the below picture:
[image]
Please help me with this

Comment: The interface named `eth0` does not exist, your interface has a different name, use `ifconfig -a` to list the existing interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace eth0 with the name of your internet card (device)
just run ifconfig alone , you will get list of your devices with information of each device ,on the left is the name of the device then there is : and couple of lines of information, replace eth0 with the name of your device